# Typing and Windows 8 - Lag of .5s

Tags: windows-8, mouse, gaming

Sorry to be asking so much in the 8 tag, but I'm having "growing pains".

I am having problems with Windows 8 and mouse performance:

While gaming, I noticed that **there is lag of approximately 500 milliseconds after the last key release** before the mouse pointer will move.  I guess this has been implemented because Microsoft wants to help out RT users, but it's REALLY a problem for me.  How can I disable it in Windows 8 Pro 64-bit?

I know, or at least am pretty sure, that this is not my touchpad malfunctioning.  I have a little icon in my taskbar that shows whether the touchpad is activated (left/right-click or touchpad), and I can see that it activated but the mouse *pointer* does not move.

I recently installed touchpad drivers, so the driver is the latest one (at [this question](https://superuser.com/q/496290/131357)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Elantech`, change `Smartpad\DisableWhenType_Enable`  from 1 to 0.

On the second question, Microsoft has specified this and cannot be removed.

Comment: Touchpad drivers are fully updated - in fact, there's a question thread about it [here](http://superuser.com/q/496290/131357).  Thank you for the info about the second question.

Comment: Oh, in this situation, check the drivers or in Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Devices and Printers > Mouse and make the  PalmCheck setting under Sensitivity smaller.

Comment: Where?  Under the Mouse dialogue window, I don't see a sensitivity tab.

Comment: (You get an upvote for Microsoft policy; I was unaware.)

Comment: Oh, wait you have the Elantech drivers. In HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Elantech, change Smartpad\DisableWhenType_Enable from 1 to 0.

Comment: OK.  Mind putting this stuff in your answer for other users?  Thanks for your help!